# QGIS: Order of WMS layers is reverse

Tags: qgis, wms

I have WMS MapService that publicized with ArcGISServer 10.4:

[image]

When I connect the WMS in QGIS the order of layers seems to be the reverse:

[image]

Has anyone encountered similar problem already?

Comment: Are those multiple WMS layers that are overlayed or is it one WMS that contains multiple layers? Please provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to resolve this.

1. Customize external capabilities files for WMS services hosted on ArcGIS Server.  That can be accomplished by following these steps to change the capabilities file and the file can be edited and layers ordered however desired.  https://enterprise.arcgis.com/en/server/latest/publish-services/windows/using-external-capabilities-files-with-wms-services.htm
2. Use the layer order tab in Qgis to arrange the layers to draw as desired.  https://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_ogc/ogc_client_support.html#loading-wms-wmts-layers

ArcGIS Server orders layers in a GetCapabilities WMS request from bottommost at layer the top of the XML to the topmost at the bottom.  This is similar to the GetMap request standard but there are no standards for layer order in a GetCapabilities response.

Qgis uses the layer order in the GetCapabilities XML to arrange the layers in its GetMap request but inverts the layer order resulting in the display issue you are experiencing.

For details on the OpenGIS Web Map Service Client (WMS) Implementation Specification 1.3.0 see http://www.opengeospatial.org/standards/wms. Section 7.2.4 provides details on the GetCapabilities response.  Section 7.3.3.3 discusses the LAYERS parameter in the GetMap request.